Viewing Large Drawing File(dwg) with Discipline layers in Forge Viewer after converting it to F2d/Pdf by Model Derivative API
I have a large drawing file (2d) for Building floors, with layers in it for Electrical wires, HAVC and Plumbing.
I used Model Derivative API for converting the dwg file in SVF(F2D) file.
After conversion when I try to view the same in Forge Viewer without turning the Discipline layers on it keeps on re-rendering some small components because of which when I turn on the Layers they also flicker and makes it hard for render the full drawing, it's always in a constant Loading/Rendering phase.
The issue is more complicated to replicate as the same doesn't happen on my smartphone (Samsung S23), but all iOS devices have this Issue on (Safari, Edge, Chrome).
Testing it on Desktops with decent configuration (GPU and CPU), It doesn't flicker on Microsoft Edge, but on Google Chrome it has the issue.
I tried converting the files as SVF2(F2D) for testing if it resolves the issue, but it didn't solve.
More testing by downgrading Forge Viewer to 7.62, 7.98, 7.96 also didn't help.
I just want to know how the same forge viewer version works differently with Chrome and Edge,
Chrome and Edge use same Rendering engine (Chromium).

The performance of the viewer may vary across browsers/systems/devices as each different environment may have different resource restrictions.
Here's a couple of things to try:

In the chromium-based browsers, try going to chrome://gpu, and check if the WebGL2 hardware acceleration is active.
In the viewer, go to Settings > Configuration, and disable Progressive display. This will render the full drawing on each frame, even if the rendering needs more time (which may have a negative impact on the overall framerate).

If you still need help with the rendering performance, please contact our official support channel with all the details of your situation, and if possible, including a sample drawing to reproduce the issues on our side (confidentially - the design would not be shared with anyone outside of Autodesk).

Thanks for your response, it was helpful and I was able to resolve this already. Moreover I was able to test accross multiple devices and one my extensions were causing it to rerender.
